# what happens if I use guard let ... { return } in init()?

Tags: swift

what happens if after guard let I return from init? I know that if it's a failable init(like init?) it returns nil.

```
    init(_ quoteRequest: QuoteRequest?, buy: Bool = true) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    guard let quoteRequest = quoteRequest else { return }
    self.quoteRequest = quoteRequest
    self.buy = buy
}
```

does object initializes? or partly? don't get it

I did't get any errors, but I don't understand what happend.

Comment: As `quoteRequest` is optional implement a failable initializer. Or make `quoteRequest` non-optional and check before calling the init method. Everything else makes no sense.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `quoteRequest` and `buy` properties. Since your code doesn't error, I assume they are optional or unowned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code compiles, clearly your `quoteRequest` and `buy` do not *need* initialization. (They must already have a value, even if it is just nil.)

So the answer to your question is: initialization of your object succeeded and ended when you said `super.init`.

Everything after that is just normal code. It runs or it doesn't, based on the guard statement, with no effect on actual initialization. Basically you are saying, okay, initialization is finished, now here's some addition optional stuff that you might do.

(It also occurs to me that this might more sense as a convenience initializer, since you are always calling the designated initializer anyway and you have no specialized designated-initializer work to do.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess `self.buy` is either an optional Bool, or has a default value :

```swift
var buy: Bool?
// OR
var buy: Bool = true // or false
```

So what happens, is that if `quoteRequest` is nil, the `guard` instructions returns, so `self.quoteRequest` and `self.buy` are left unchanged (they do not take into account `init` parameters).
And if `quoteRequest` is not nil, then they are both initialized with constructor's parameters values.

It would be equivalent (but arguably worse) to write :

```swift
init(_ quoteRequest: QuoteRequest?, buy: Bool = true)
{
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    if let quoteRequest = quoteRequest // quoteRequest != nil
    {
        self.quoteRequest = quoteRequest
        self.buy = quoteRequest != nil ? buy : nil
    }
}
```